# Send $_POST to 2 php files at once

Tags: php, post

i have no idea how to solve a problem with sending $_POST. I want to fill a form at example.com

```
//at example.com
<form action="foo.php" method="post" >
<input name="bar1" type="text" />
<input name="bar2" type="text" />
<input name="bar3" type="text" />
<input value="Send" type="submit" />
</form>
```

and then it goes to foo.php :

```
<?php //foo.php
echo 'added: <p>'.$_POST['bar1'].'<br />'.$_POST['bar2'].'<br />'.$_POST['bar3']; 
?>
```

and in the same time it also send

```
$_POST['bar1'], $_POST['bar2'], $_POST['bar3']
```

to exampledomain.com/foobar.php where it can be saved to a file - that's not a problem.

I don't know how to send info to both php scripts at once - one is external one. I guess i have to send it somehow inside foo.php

There is kind of solution - redirecting to exampledomain.com/foobar.php inside foo.php but it isn't acceptable in my case - I want to do it without making user exit example.com

Thanks in advance and hope you can undestand my problem - if not just ask a comment

EDIT: Based on Pete Herbert Penito's answer:

```
 <?php //inside foo.php
 $url = 'http://exampledomain.com/foobar.php';
 $fields_string='';
 foreach($_POST as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
 rtrim($fields_string,'&');

 //open connection
 $ch = curl_init();

 //set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($_POST));
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);

 //execute post
 $result = curl_exec($ch);

 //close connection
 curl_close($ch);

  ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use CURL to construct a post request:

```
<?php
 // these variables would need to be changed to be your variables 
 // alternatively you could send the entire post constructed using a foreach
 if(isset($_POST['Name']))     $Name   = $_POST['Name'];
 if(isset($_POST['Email']))   $Email   = $_POST['Email'];
 if(isset($_POST['Message']))   $Message= htmlentities($_POST['Message']);

 $Curl_Session = curl_init('http://www.site.com/cgi-bin/waiting.php');
 curl_setopt ($Curl_Session, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
 curl_setopt ($Curl_Session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "Name=$Name&Email=$Email&Message=$Message");
 curl_setopt ($Curl_Session, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
 curl_exec ($Curl_Session);
 curl_close ($Curl_Session);
?>
```

From Link:

http://www.askapache.com/php/sending-post-form-data-php-curl.html

Comment: This method will result in the second webserver seeing the POST as coming from the initial webserver, not the user - may or may not be desirable

Comment: Considering the originating server name hasn't been mentioned in the question. I take your point though, it wouldn't be coming from the same place; however, just logging the POST variables doesn't seem to insinuate that this info is important.

Comment: i am gonna check this solution - thank you i think in my case it should work nicely

Comment: I am customizing this script - I am using foreach where you suggested - but I don't now what I should write here `curl_setopt ($Curl_Session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "Name=$Name&Email=$Email&Message=$Message");` - **"Name=$Name&Email=$Email&Message=$Message"** - I have to combine it with foreach somehow

Answer (score 1):

In your `foo.php`:

```
<?php
include 'http://exampledomain.com/foobar.php';
```

**Note:** you need to enable `allow_url_fopen` in your `php.ini` file.

Comment: That would not work, the second PHP file is on another server as he wrote in his question.

Comment: @BjörnKaiser yes, I added a note that `allow_url_fopen` should be enabled for this.

Comment: that's good solution but for saving file only - i use it as well to print some data - it would add additional content what i try to avoid - maybe somebody else can use it - thank you

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do one of the POST's with javascript ajax.

Then the real post which will redirect the browser like normal.

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_post.asp

```
$(selector).post(url,data,success(response,status,xhr),dataType)
```

Comment: You would have to prevent the submit button from actually submitting first, otherwise the ajax request wouldn't complete. That being said, it's not too difficult to create a click listener that prevents default, sends ajax request, upon completion, then redirect browser.